# How to \copy contents of a box without copying the box itself?

Tags: boxes, plain-tex

Self-describing sample

```
% pdfTeX
\newbox\thbx
\newbox\thhbx

\setbox\thbx\hbox{abc}
% HOW TO COPY THE CONTENTS OF THE BOX
%  WITHOUT ACTUALLY COPYING THE BOX
%   ITSELF ALONG WITH THOSE CONTENTS?
\setbox\thhbx\hbox{\copy\thbx}
% I NEED \hbox{abc} NOT \hbox{\hbox{abc}}

\showbox\thhbx
\bye
```

outputs

```
\thbx=\box16
\thhbx=\box17
> \box17=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
..\tenrm a
..\tenrm b
..\kern0.27779
..\tenrm c
```

but I need only `abc` copied, not the box with the `abc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: To copy a box, use `\copy`. If you don't want the enclosing `\hbox`, just don't write it. That is, instead of

```
\setbox\thhbx=\hbox{\copy\thbx}
```

write

```
\setbox\thhbx=\copy\thbx
```

to make the box `\thhbx` be the same as `\thbx`. More generally, you can use `\unhcopy` to copy only the contents of a box, though it's not necessary here: if you used it, you'd have to enclose the results again in a box, like:

```
\setbox\thhbx=\hbox{\unhcopy\thbx}
```

which in this case is simply unnecessary compared to `\copy\thbx`.

---

Here's an example that will hopefully make everything clear:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{ab}              % The original box
\setbox1=\hbox{xy\copy0 rs}
\setbox2=\hbox{\copy0}
\setbox3=\copy0                 % Now box 3 is identical to box 0
\setbox4=\hbox{xy\unhcopy0 rs}
\setbox5=\hbox{\unhcopy0}       % Now box 5 is identical to box 0
```

The rest of this answer is just an elaboration of the above example.

---

Suppose you write

```
\setbox0=\hbox{ab}
```

Then box 0 is the following:

```
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm b
```

So when you use it in bigger boxes, either destructively with `\box` or nondestructively with `\copy`, you'll get the box. For example, if you write

```
\setbox1=\hbox{xy\copy0 rs}
```

you get:

```
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x28.9723
.\tenrm x
.\tenrm y
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
..\tenrm a
..\tenrm b
.\tenrm r
.\tenrm s
```

where there's a box in place of `\copy0`. Similarly if you write

```
\setbox2=\hbox{\copy0}
```

you'll get box 2 to be

```
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
..\tenrm a
..\tenrm b
```

similar to the situation in the question.

When copying to another box, if you don't want an *additional* outer enclosing `\hbox`, then just don't write it! So if you write

```
\setbox3=\copy0
```

you'll get box 3 to be

```
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm b
```

the same as the original box 0.

In cases where this cannot be used, you can copy just the “contents” (stripping out the other box) with either `\unhbox` (destructively) or `\unhcopy` (nondestructively). (Similarly `\unvbox` and `\unvcopy` for vertical boxes.) So for example:

```
\setbox4=\hbox{xy\unhcopy0 rs}
```

gives

```
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x28.9723
.\tenrm x
.\tenrm y
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm b
.\tenrm r
.\tenrm s
```

and

```
\setbox5=\hbox{\unhcopy0}
```

gives

```
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.55559
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm b
```

again the same as the original box 0.

Comment: @bp2017 That seems the same as the question you asked. Is there anything unanswered by the answer above? (Again, to repeat, you can copy the vbox with `\copy` *without* an unnecessary `\vbox` enclosing it, or copy just the contents with `\unvcopy` and then enclose it again in a vbox.)

Comment: `\unhcopy` does not work when you "unpack" contents of a horizontal box inside a vertical box (because of additional space and glue).

Comment: @bp2017 Yeah it doesn't make sense to do that anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to recover the content of a \vbox?  \unvbox put out preformatted lines.

Comment: @JohnKormylo (If I understand your question correctly...) Careful about what you mean by "content". Once you've defined a vbox with say `\setbox0=...`, then the *actual* contents of the box, *as shown by* `\showbox0`, are what you'll get with `\unvbox` or `\unvcopy`. If you mean the specification you typed (e.g. you typed `\vbox{abc}` and want to recover "abc"), then that never goes into the box; it's gone even before the original box is created.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - I am looking for a way to automatically reformat paragraphs at a change in \columnwidth caused by flowfram.  It would be nice to be able to reformat \AP@partial (afterpage package).  Alas, that would be too easy.